# How to stop SilentCleanServer app from running

Tags: macos

I have an old iMac running High Sierra. Using Activity Monitor I noticed that I have an app named SilentCleanServer running  This program is using some CPU time and it has over 2,000 files associated with it. From looking at other sites this app is from Mobi. I would like to stop this app but can't manage to do so. From Activity Monitor I can quit the app but it immediately restarts. When I try to delete the app it says it can't because app is open. But when I kill it, it restarts before I can delete it. I don't necessarily want to delete the app if I can just stop it from running.

Is there a way to stop this app from restarting?

Comment: [This discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7357184) at Apple Community should give you some clues as to how to stop this.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks, there was a simple solution given in this discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Apple Community discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7357184) may have the answer:

> Try deleting the "com.imobie.PhoneClean" and "com.iMobie.SilentCleanServer" folders in ~/Library/Application Support.

or

> Theres an underlying silentcleanserver app, which is located once you "show all contents". I uninstalled and its gone!